# How to translate "as long as you" (time comparison)

Tags: português-brasileiro, expressões-idiomáticas

I am trying to find a Brazilian portuguese translation for the phrase *"I have been doing this for as long as you"* or *"I have been here as long as you have been here."*

Is there an idiomatic way to translate "as long as you" in this specific context?

Note: I am not looking for the translation in the sense of requirement, e.g. "You can come as long as you bring the snacks". Just in terms of **time comparison**.

Comment: Yes, well, this: "I have been doing this for as long as you" is poor English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In pt-BR the most common translation for "I have been doing this for as long as you" would be:

- Eu faço isso há tanto tempo quanto você.

And, for "I have been here as long as you have been here.":

- Eu estou aqui há tanto tempo quanto você (está).

Alternatives to "*há tanto tempo quanto você*" include:

- Faz tanto tempo quanto você.
- Por tanto tempo quanto você.
- Pelo mesmo tempo que você.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is *há tanto tempo como tu* or, less commonly, *há tanto tempo quanto tu*.

> Faço isto **há tanto tempo quanto tu**.
> Estou cá **há tanto tempo como tu**.

*Quanto* is less common in the example sentences above, but sounds better if the clause following it is more developed:

> Estou cá há tanto tempo quanto tu estiveste no Brasil.

Comment: Boas-vindas ao Portuguese SE, Fidel. Obrigado pela contribuição. Vale notar que em pt-br (como pedido na pergunta) o "tu" é menos comum e a construção com o "como" ainda menos.